# visa.resourcemanager('@py') show no instruments

Tags: pyvisa

I have a hardware setup where several instruments are connected to the control computer. The `pyvisa` default back-end, a C implementation provided by National Instruments, found all the instruments, while the `pyvisa-py` pure-Python implementation did not find any.

I'm using the latest versions of `pyvisa` and `pyvisa-py`. I used the following code to search for instruments, using both back-ends.

```
import visa
rm_py = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
rm_ni = visa.ResourceManager()
rm_py.list_resources()
rm_ni.list_resources()
```

With `rm_py.list_resources()`, I got `()`, meaning no device detected.

With `rm_ni.list_resources()` on the other hand, I got:

```
'('TCPIP0::169.254.172.70::INSTR',
'TCPIP0::192.168.3.10::inst0::INSTR',
'ASRL3::INSTR',
'GPIB0::28::INSTR',
'TCPIP0::AWG70K-38293801::inst0::INSTR')'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Win or Linux?

Comment: please don't say Mac, now.

Comment: The OS is Win10.

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux

Comment: For Linux have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66480539/8849755).

Comment: @user171780 could you try visa.ResourceManager('@py')? This script uses the pyvisa-py backend. If you have IVI libraries from NIvisa, Tekvisa,etc, visa.ResourceManager() usually autmatically leads to this IVIs instead of pure python backend.